# Can a same program return different results on Matlab & Octave?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, octave

```
I = imread('C:\Users\hp\Desktop\octave folder\cameraman.png');    
figure, imshow(I);    
J = imnoise(I,'salt & pepper',0.02);    
figure, imshow(J);  
A = J;  
ref = I;  
[peaksnr, snr] = psnr(A, ref);        

  fprintf('\n The Peak-SNR value is %0.4f', peaksnr);
  fprintf('\n The SNR value is %0.4f \n', snr);

Kaverage = filter2(fspecial('average',3),J)/255;
figure,imshow(Kaverage);
%% 

%%The folloeing section is providing different results on matlab & octave

Kmedian = medfilt2(J);  
figure,imshow(Kmedian);    
A= Kmedian;   
ref=J;   
[peaksnr, snr] = psnr(A, ref);

fprintf('\n The Peak-SNR value is %0.4f', peaksnr);  
fprintf('\n The SNR value is %0.4f \n', snr);
```

I have 2 problems regarding the above code

1. Providing different PSNR & SNR values on Matlab and Ovtave
2. The values of "I" & "Kaverage" are not of same class, so we cant get the  PSNR between them.   How can we convert both to same class?

Comment: Use the name of the class you desire. `I=double(I)`, or `uint8` or `single` or any of the others

Comment: An insigned integer, a U-INT, not an UNIT of 8.

Comment: Sir, as we knou to find PSNR both the images (ref, I) should be of same class. Here ( I is uint8) & (Kaverage is double) now when I am converting (I to doubles) it is showing improved results and when I am converting (kaverage to uint8) it shows degraded results, Why so?  @ Ander Biguri

Comment: Becuase of the representation of the data. When you convert to uint8, you loose information due to discratization

Comment: For the same case how can i convert 'uint8' type image to 'logical'

Comment: We am not your personal Google.